# Return all mySQL Records for Current Year

Tags: mysql

In mySQL, I would like to return a count of the records that have a `start_date` within the current year (as in the year 2012, NOT within the last one year time period) and (as a separate query) a count of the records from the previous year (2011 in the case as it is now).

My start dates are stored thus: `2012-12-02`. I am using PHP.

Help on how I would form these queries would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
 FROM TABLE1
 WHERE YEAR(START_DATE) = YEAR(CURDATE());
```

Comment: Not sure that it is a good decision. If You have the index on START_DATE it will not work. Better to make all preparations in the right part of condition. Something like this START_DATE > DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-01-01 00:00:01')

Answer (score 8):

You may want to use [**YEAR**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) function to get the YEAR from the date and use the same in comparison.

```
 SELECT COUNT(*)
 FROM TABLE1
 WHERE YEAR(START_DATE) = 2012;
```

Separate query from previous year:

```
 SELECT COUNT(*)
 FROM TABLE1
 WHERE YEAR(START_DATE) = 2011;
```

To get the year wise counts:

```
 SELECT COUNT(b.YEAR), b.YEAR
 FROM TABLE1 AS a JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(START_DATE) AS YEAR from TABLE1) AS b
    ON YEAR(START_DATE) = b.YEAR
 GROUP BY b.YEAR;
```

Comment: But that would require I manually change the hard-coded year each year. I'd like that bit to be automatic.

Comment: `WHERE YEAR(START_DATE) = YEAR(NOW())`

Comment: You can set the 2012 or 2011 in the query to be a variable inside of PHP, so it will be automatic / dynamic.

Comment: @user1857692 You asked for a separate query `as a separate query` hence that way. Let me update the answer with year wise counts.

Answer (score 2):

Two suggestions:

You can filter your data using dates:

```
select count(*) from tbl where start_date >= '2012-01-01'
```

or

```
select count(*) from tbl where start_date between '2012-01-01' and '2012-12-31'
```

Also, you can filter your data using the `year()` function:

```
select count(*) from tbl where year(start_date) = 2012
```

Hope this helps you

---

If you are using PHP (or any other high level programming language), you can build your query string on runtime to fit your needs (e.g. To filter records from different years).

To show the count of records with `start_date` before 2012, just change the `where` conditions:

```
select... where year(start_date) < 2012
```

or

```
select... where start_date < '2012-01-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

As Rostyslav Pylypenko points out in a comment above, the accepted answer will not use indices.  A better way to get records in the current year is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `table`
WHERE start_date >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-01-01');
```

You can apply the same logic to get count for previous year:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `table`
WHERE start_date >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR ,'%Y-01-01')
    AND start_date < DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-01-01');
```